# Attribute "rendered" check for the size and condition

Tags: visualforce

How can I fit this two condition in rendered?

I have the following condition

```
rendered="{!detailList.size!=0}" rendered={!bShowDetail}
```

I have tried the following:

```
rendered="{!(detailList.size!=0) && (!bShowDetail)}"
```

and this:

```
rendered="{!detailList.size!=0 && !bShowDetail}"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax should be `{!detailList.size!=0 && bShowDetail}`. In a merge formula, the general syntax is `{!` **formula** `}`, so you should only use ! once at the beginning to indicate the merge formula, rather than at the beginning of each field. If it's not working, make sure your list is not empty and that bShowDetail is actually true.

Comment: You're not following your own advice about using `!` only once.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Doh. That was poorly worded. One sec.